# Python: what's with variable = arguments inversion with 'argv' or return?

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax

So a typical way to assign arguments to a variable in python is:

```
variable_name = "argument name as a string"
```

or

```
variable_name = 1
```

---

With 'argv' or return in a function, the whole syntax is inverted:

```
argument_name1, argument_name2 = argv
```

or

```
def function_name(a):
    a = 1
    b = a + 1
    return a, b

a, b = function(1)
```

What's the deal with this inversion? Is it something I need to remember, or is there a logic behind this that can be applied to more things?

Comment: Um, what do you mean by the "way to assign arguments to a variable `variable_name = "argument name as a string`"?  What is "argv"? You are essentially showing different examples of unpacking.

Comment: @depperm the function returns one value, that happens to be iterable, and when iterated over, has two elements in it, technically.

Comment: From the docs: "If the target list is a comma-separated list of targets: The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets in the target list, and the items are assigned, from left to right, to the corresponding targets."

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I assign two arguments to 'argv' from left to right and variable name is on the left, while making a simple variable can be done a = "a text that I want to input"

Comment: You are not. You are always assigning from right to left. Have a look at my answer below.

Comment: @tentkl those aren't arguments, and you are assigning to multiple variables on the *left*

Comment: `argument_name1, argument_name2 = argv` does not assign anything to `argv`. It takes the values in `argv` and puts them in `argument_name_1` and `argument_name_2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inversion in your examples.

The = sign assigns whatever is on the right of it to whatever is on the left to it.

Here, you assign values to a new variable:

```
variable_name = "argument name as a string"
variable_name = 1
```

In the function, you assign the output of the function (right) to the variables on the left:

```
def function_name(a):
    a = 1
    b = a + 1
    return a, b

a, b = function_name(1)
```

If your confusion comes from the comma, it basically allows you to assign two variables at the same time.

`function_name(1)` returns `(a,b)`

```
a, b = function_name(1)
```

is simply short for:

```
output = function_name(1) # Output is (a, b)
a = output[0]
b = output[1]
```

However, I think you are confused about the general concept of assignment. The function takes an argument a, but then overrides the argument with 1.

It should be either:

```
def function_name():
    a = 1
    b = a + 1
    return a, b
```

or

```
def function_name(a):
    b = a + 1
    return a, b
```

Here is how you can test your claim that you are assigning from left to right:

```
argument_name1 = 'a'
argument_name2 = 'b'
argument_name1, argument_name2 = argv
print argv
```

Will throw the error NameError: name 'argv' is not defined

But:

```
argv = ('a', 'b')
argument_name1, argument_name2 = argv
print(argument_name1, argument_name2)
```

prints: `a b`

Comment: FYI, it returns a tuple `(a,b)`, not a list `[a,b]` (technically)

Comment: @LukasAnsteeg but theres a difference where values are placed in 'argv' and other examples. with 'argv' you first list values and then assign it to 'argv', while in other case you first call a variable and then assign it to a value. Am I missing something? I'm new to programming, so sorry about this stupid thread

Comment: No worries, I programmed for years before switching to Python, and the comma notation confused me for a while too.

What makes you think that argument_name1, argument_name2 = argv assigns from left to right? Have you tested it?

Comment: I've added a test to the bottom of my answer which you can run to confirm that assignment is always from right to left :)

Comment: @LukasAnsteeg To be honest im more confused about ‘argv’ (sys.argv) and how its values are assigned from left to right (e.g script_name, input_file = argv)

Comment: Please check the new part I added to the bottom of my answer

Comment: @LukasAnsteeg ok, this blew my mind; that is pretty confusing to be honest

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is not inverted. Python actuallly allows you to unpack the variable on the fly. The function actually returns a tuple

```
def function_name(a):
    a = 1
    b = a + 1
    return a, b
```

If you test the function return type, you get:

```
>>> type(function_name(1))
<type 'tuple'>
```

This syntax actually prevents you from wirting this

```
value = function_name(1)  # value = (1, 2)
a = value[0]  # a = 1
b = value[1]  # b = 2
```